# Fax in Delphi XE5 using AsyncPro

Tags: delphi, fax

I would like to automatically fax by Windows Fax from an application. Windows Fax is using a USB-Faxmodem which is connected to a faxserver. The phone connection is established via POTS.

I'm using the environment of Delphi XE5 und the components of TurboPower AsyncPro 5.0. The COM Port of the Faxmodem is 3 (I already checked this). In the variable strCall is the text which should be faxed. It looks well to me but I always receive the error 'ie-badid specified com port doesn't exist'. Do I need another component to establish the connection or what can be the reason?

```
ApdComPort1.ComNumber:= 3;
ApdComPort1.Open:= true;

meoFaxText.Lines.Add(strCall);
meoFaxText.Lines.SaveToFile(ExtractFilePath(Paramstr(0)) + 'outfax.txt');
ApdFaxConverter1.DocumentFile:= ExtractFilePath(Paramstr(0)) + 'outfax.txt';
ApdFaxConverter1.InputDocumentType:= idText;
ApdFaxConverter1.OutFileName:= ExtractFilePath(Paramstr(0)) + 'outfax.apf';
ApdFaxConverter1.ConvertToFile;

ApdSendFax1.FaxFile:= ApdFaxConverter1.OutFileName;
ApdSendFax1.PhoneNumber:= '0123456789';
ApdSendFax1.StartTransmit;
```

Comment: Is the com port already in use by some other software (maybe a fax program running in the background?)

Comment: It's been a while, but isn't Windows Fax an application (or server) and as such has the port open (as @Dsm suggests)? AsyncPro, on the other hand, assumes that it should do everything and has exclusive ownership of the COM port for the duration of the transmission.